# Numerical Iteration Python

Tags: arrays, syntax, indexoutofboundsexception, numerical-methods

for the following code:

```
from array import *
x=[]
x.append(0.232)
print (x)
for i in range(25):
 x[i+1]=(1/(i+1))-5*x[i]
```

I have this error:

```
x[i+1]=(1/(i+1))-5*x[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

This may be happening because I have defined x to be an empty array. But how do I define the array and perform the same operation otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is not designed for efficient mathematical operations and therefore its better to use `numpy` arrays for doing mathematical operations. However, if you want to use list, you may define a list initialized with `n` zero's using

```
x=[0]*n
x[0] = 0.232
x[1] = ....
....
```

Remember, that a multidimensional `list` created using above approach will refer to same element in the array! For example:

```
l = [0,0,0]*5
```

will be creating five same `list`'s inside another `list` not separate `list`'s. So its a bad idea to create multidimensional array like this!

A better way would be to create arrays using numpy using following code:

```
from numpy import empty, zeros
x = empty(n) # or # x = zeros(n)
x[0] = 0.232
x[1] = ....
....
```

and

```
l = empty((3,5)) # or # l = zeros((3,5))
```

for a array with 3 rows and 5 columns.